# How to check if no message has been sent for X minutes? (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to do a command where the bot sends a random topic when no message has been sent for the time the user specifies, however, I can't seem to get the timing part right.

My question is: How do I check if no message has been sent in a channel for X minutes?
Here is the code I came up with:

```
@bot.command()
async def timedtopic(ctx, time : int):
    global keepLooping
    timer = dt.datetime.utcnow() + dt.timedelta(seconds=time)
    keepLooping = True
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Reviver's topic is", description=(random.choice(List)))
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    while keepLooping:
        if timer > ctx.channel.last_message.created_at and ctx.channel.last_message.author != bot.user:
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
channel = ctx.channel
async for message in channel.history(limit = 1):
    past_message = message.created_at
await asyncio.sleep(time)
async for message in channel.history(limit = 1):
    new_message = message.created_at
if past_message == new_message:
    print(f"No message has been sent in {time} seconds!")
```