# Bot sends a message if there have been no messages sent in a channel for a specified time

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

so I'm currently trying to make a command that watches over a channel and if there are no messages sent in the last x minutes it will send a message

my code is:

```
@client.command()
async def watch(ctx, time : int):
  channel = ctx.channel
  async for message in channel.history(limit = 1):
    past_message = message.created_at
  await asyncio.sleep(time)
  async for message in channel.history(limit = 1):
    new_message = message.created_at
  if past_message == new_message:
    if not new_message:
      channel = client.get_channel(816741369682985012)
      await channel.send("<@400349192125415436> bot is down")
```

i got the code from
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63487891/how-to-check-if-no-message-has-been-sent-for-x-minutes-discord-py) but this command will send me the message only if the there are no message sent after I use the command, if there is any messages the command will stop or after the warn message is sent the command stops watching, I want to make it so its always watching the the channel

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check the channel, after you execute the command, you could simply run it in loop

```py
@client.command()
async def watch(ctx, time : int):
  channel = ctx.channel
  while True:
    async for message in channel.history(limit = 1):
      past_message = message.created_at
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    async for message in channel.history(limit = 1):
      new_message = message.created_at
    if past_message == new_message:
      channel = client.get_channel(816741369682985012)
      await channel.send("<@400349192125415436> bot is down")
```

With this however, you will have to use the command to start watching.

---

If you want to start watching without using a command, you will need to register the function in your client main-loop.

```py
async def watch():
  channel = client.get_channel(816741369682985012)
  while True:
    async for message in channel.history(limit = 1):
      past_message = message.created_at
    await asyncio.sleep(time)
    async for message in channel.history(limit = 1):
      new_message = message.created_at
    if past_message == new_message:
      await channel.send("<@400349192125415436> bot is down")
```

And then register the function via

```py
client.loop.create_task(watch())
```

Comment: uh, I tried both the command and the function, and none of them worked, they don't send me the message to warn me about the inactivity, maybe I'm too dumb

Comment: Ah, maybe try without the `if not new_message:`